# action not firing after you click yes in the confirm dialog window

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

Hi I have this line of code:

```
<a4j:commandButton id='forceBtn'
     disabled='false'
     rendered='true'
     value="Force"
     reRender="notesPopupFragment"
     action=='#{setUpController}'
     onclick='return confirm("Are you sure?")'>
     <a:actionparam value="true" assignTo="#{popup.show}" noEscape="true" />
```

after the user click yes in the confirm dialog its not firing the action

Comment: You likely killed the `onclick` handler RichFaces placed on the rendered button. The way I did this is by hiding the "real" button and "clicking" it dynamically. In RF-4.x there's the `onstart` attribute you can hook into w/o messing the process up.

Comment: thanks for you answer mabi, can you give me a code snippet regarding the onstart?

Comment: Thou your code snippet suggests you're using RF-3.x?

Comment: yup its rf-3.x can you provide me your sample?

Comment: are you also suggesting that if i change the rerender this will work?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure if your commandButton is surrounded by `<h:form>...</h:form>` component, and if your form doesn't contain inputs that are `required` or their values aren't validated (as that would prevent action from fire).